# using for loop to create gridmap

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop

I have created a for loop to produce a grid map. When I click each grid on the map I get X and Y of the grid. When map width is greater than map length, everything is fine, but when attempt to create a map where length is greater than with, the returned x becomes the y, and y becomes the x. The issue is at the second for loop when creating the map but I cannot figure it out.

```
if(mapWidth>mapLength) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mapWidth * mapLength; i++) {
        y = i / mapLength;

        for(int j=0; j<i+1; j++) {
            x = j % mapLength;
        }

        GridPanel gb = new GridPanel(x, y);
        list.add(gb);
        mapPanel.add(gb);
    }
} else if(mapWidth<mapLength) { //problematic map is created after this condition
    for (int i = 0; i < mapWidth * mapLength; i++) {
        x = i / mapLength;  
        for(int j=0; j < i+1; j++){
            y = j % mapLength;
        }

        GridPanel gb = new GridPanel(x, y);
        list.add(gb);
        mapPanel.add(gb);
    }
}
```

Maps look like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why not just use two loops? `for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) { (int y = 0; y < mapLength; y++) { ... }}`

Comment: @flkes well that would only create the X axis of the map.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe I didn't understand well what you expect but I don't think you have to make a special case for the case where `mapWidth`< `mapLength`.
Furthermore, I don't get what you intend to do with your nested loop except using CPU resources?

```
    for(int j=0; j<i+1; j++){
        x = j % mapLength;
    }
```

When it is left, you will always have `x` = `i % mapLength`

Furthermore, as flkes suggested, why don't you use nested loops?

```
for (int y=0; y < mapLength; y++) {
    for(int x=0; x < mapWidth; x++){
       GridPanel gb = new GridPanel(x, y);
       list.add(gb);
       mapPanel.add(gb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mapWidth * mapLength; i++) {
    y = i / mapLength;
    x = i % mapLength;

    GridPanel gb = new GridPanel(x, y);
    list.add(gb);
    mapPanel.add(gb);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i can click from x:0, y:0 to x:3 ,x:3, after that rest of the grids give error. Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 90, Size: 40

Comment: @PRCube I think you should provide more code because I think that there issues outside the code you provided.